# Variadic template chooses more common template instead of overload

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

Imagine this code:

```
#include <iostream>
void PrintInternal() {
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

template <typename T, typename...ARGS>
void PrintInternal(const T& head, const ARGS&...rest) {
    std::cout << head << " ";
    PrintInternal(rest...);
};

template <typename...ARGS>
void PrintInternal(const double& head, const ARGS&...rest) {
    std::cout << "DBL!!! " << head << " ";
    PrintInternal(rest...);
}

template <typename...ARGS>
void Print(const ARGS&...args) {
    PrintInternal(args...);
}

int main() {
    Print(1.1, 2, 3.3, 4);
    Print(0, 1.1, 2, 3.3, 4);
    return 0;
}
```

First `Print` outputs:

> DBL!!! 1.1 2 3.3 4

My expectations were, that it would output DBL!!! before 3.3 or no DBL!!! at all. But why one???

Second `Print` outputs:

> 0 1.1 2 3.3 4

Why there is no DBL!!! output like at all, if we had one in first example.

And how to achieve, that for each `double` I will output something different without partial specialization? I've thought, that simple overloading should be ok...

Link to cpp.sh to view compilation results -> http://cpp.sh/42cz

Comment: Take a closer look and be careful. The second print has 0 as the 1st parameter, right? (0 suppose to have integer type). Your "DBL!!" takes 1st parameter as double.
Say, if you'd tried 0. or 0.0 it would have worked

Comment: Yep, you are correct here, thanks, However, more mysteries remains unsolved :)

Comment: The order of template functions is important.  All functions the template calls need to be visible before the call.

Comment: I recommend you to read more about parameters substitution.
Say, as you have array of double and you have overloaded foo(double) against template<typename T>foo(T) - double always wins.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lookup for `PrintInternal()` is going to find two types of functions:

- All the functions visible at the point of definition of the function template.
- All the functions in the associated namespaces of the dependent arguments of the function template.

In this case, all of our arguments are fundamental types, so there aren't any associated namespaces. That makes things easier. So when we start with:

```
#include <iostream>
void PrintInternal() { // #1
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

template <typename T, typename...ARGS>
void PrintInternal(const T& head, const ARGS&...rest) { // #2
    std::cout << head << " ";
    PrintInternal(rest...); // <== (*)
};

template <typename...ARGS>
void PrintInternal(const double& head, const ARGS&...rest) { // #3
    std::cout << "DBL!!! " << head << " ";
    PrintInternal(rest...);
}
```

That marked call to `PrintInteral()` only has two candidates: the nullary function (#1) and itself (#2). The other one, the more specialized `PrintInteral()` that takes a `const double&` (#3) isn't visible yet, so is never considered as a candidate. It's not that #2 was preferred to #3, it's just that it was the only option.

If you flip the ordering of the two overloads, then you'd have a different problem - you wouldn't be able to find #2!

This gives you a few options:

1. Separate out printing an individual element from printing all of the elements. This way, you just have to overload `PrintSingle()`, which is easier  to do.
2. Forward-declare all your function templates so that they're all visible.
3. Introduce another argument solely for the purpose of that second bullet point on top applying. Just a dummy argument that exists just to do name lookup with ADL. This solution is sometimes necessary, but always confusing:

   ```
   namespace N {
       struct adl { };

       void PrintInternal(adl ) {
           std::cout << std::endl;
       }

       template <typename T, typename...ARGS>
       void PrintInternal(adl, const T& head, const ARGS&...rest) {
           std::cout << head << " ";
           PrintInternal(adl{}, rest...);
       }

       template <typename...ARGS>
       void PrintInternal(adl, const double& head, const ARGS&...rest) {
           std::cout << "DBL!!! " << head << " ";
           PrintInternal(adl{}, rest...);
       }
   }

   template <typename...ARGS>
   void Print(const ARGS&...args) {
       PrintInternal(N::adl{}, args...);
   }
   ```

Comment: Why flipping ordering hides its own definition ?

Comment: @Jarod42 If the `T` overload goes first, it can't see the `double` one. If the `double` one goes first, it can't see the `T` one. Same problem either way.

Comment: Yeah, We just have to forward declare the function.

Answer (score 0):

You have problem of visibility, you may fix it by forward declaration:

```
template <typename...ARGS> void PrintInternal(const double& head, const ARGS&...rest);

template <typename T, typename...ARGS>
void PrintInternal(const T& head, const ARGS&...rest) {
    std::cout << head << " ";
    PrintInternal(rest...);
}

template <typename...ARGS>
void PrintInternal(const double& head, const ARGS&...rest) {
    std::cout << "DBL!!! " << head << " ";
    PrintInternal(rest...);
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/qIuO9T)

Simpler would be to have the specific only for the simple print, and have the recursion apart, something like:

```
void printSingle(double d)
{
    std::cout << "DBL!!! " << d << " ";
}

template <typename T>
void printSingle(const T& t)
{
    std::cout << t << " ";
}

template <typename...ARGS>
void Print(const ARGS&...args) {
    const int dummy[] = {0, (printSingle(args), 0)...};
    static_cast<void>(dummy); // Avoid warning for unused variable
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/7YYcGy)

Comment: DBL!!! 1.1 DBL!!! 2 DBL!!! 3.3 DBL!!! 4 
This is kinda bad output. Looks like template is not worked at all, only double overload

Comment: Changing the ordering just changes which one doesn't work as intended.

Comment: @Starl1ght: Indeed, Answer fixed.